# How to get output of terminal commands to python gui text area using subprocess?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, subprocess

```
   import subprocess
   subprocess.call('gcc a.c', shell=True)
   subprocess.call('./a.out', shell=True)
```

I am executing this statement to compile a ".c" file. I got the output in the backend.

But how can I get the output of that C program in a python text area (I'm using tkinter, python 2.7 )?

Another problem is, I'm not able to scan input data but only able to compile programs which will not take input data.

Answer (score 1):

you can use subprocess.Popen and redirect stdout to PIPE and test simply read stdout e.g `complie.stdout.readlines()` in you set text area calls

```
import subprocess

complie = subprocess.Popen('gcc a.c', stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
runprog  = subprocess.Popen('./a.out', stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)

print (complie.stdout.readlines())
print (runprog.stdout.readlines())
```

instead of prints you can put `complie.stdout.readlines()` in your text area set calls

**Example Code :**

```
import subprocess
from tkinter import *

#Example on Windows

root = Tk()
T = Text(root, height=2, width=200)
T.pack()

complie = subprocess.Popen('ping google.com', stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stdin=subprocess.PIPE ,shell=True)
complie.wait()
outcome = complie.stdout.readlines()
print(outcome)
T.insert(END, outcome)
mainloop()
```

Hope this helps